# Complex FlashVar objects using SWFObject?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, swfobject

Is it possible to pass native JavaScript objects such as arrays and hash-map-like objects to Flash Player with SWFObject?

I basically need to pass an array of objects to Flash from JavaScript in the Flash variables, so this is my code:

```
swfobject.embedSWF("application.swf", "divvy" "100%", "100%", null,
    { 'info': [
        { 'id': 1, 'name': "Hello, John" },
        { 'id': 2, 'name': "Hello, Dave" }
    }]);
```

When I get the object in Flex, I simply get a String that looks like this: "[Object object], [Object object]" which leads me to believe that my array is being serialized into a String before entering Flash. Is there any known workaround?

And yes, I do need to pass Flash variables in this manner, since they'll key off some loading which is necessary to do before the application starts.

Comment: You don't have to pass Flash variables in that manner, and in fact you can't, at least not in the way you show here. What you *can* do is let it connect to the server and get the data before you let the app begin running. Show a progress bar until your data arrives.

Comment: Dead on, thanks. I forgot that Flash vars are simply URL variables, not actual JavaScript objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: as @Robusto mentioned above **it is not possible to pass native JavaScript objects to Flash Player via Flashvars**. I forgot that Flash variables are simply GET parameters to the SWF, nothing more. Thus, `application.swf?r=123` is the same thing as `swfobject.embedSWF('application.swf', '100%', '100%', null, {'r': 123}, null);`

I'll probably just load some XML or something.

Answer (score 6):

Use the JSON lib from [as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib) and pass the entire object encoded as a json object and it will become a flash object once its deserialized.  You might need to urlencode the json string to pass it as a string, once it gets into as3 it will be de-urlencoded, and you can unserialize it using the as3corelib's json function, and you will have a object in flash that represents your data.

Answer (score 2):

The complex object must be sent as a string via flashvars, you could then use as3corelib's JSON parser to read it.

Alternatively you could use [`ExternalInterface`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) to call a javascript function to return the object as is.

As was also suggested in the comments, you could have Flash request the data from the server itself, there's a lot of ways this can be done.